# Why can't I connect to SQL Server 2016 Express from VS

Tags: sql, asp.net, ado.net

I am new at this. I am doing an ASP.NET tutorial, but I can't I connect to SQL Server 2016 Express from VS. I get the error below:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Instance failure.
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace tree_view_control_tutorial_2
{
    public partial class WebForm4 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetData(null);
            }
        }

        private void GetData(string searchTerm)
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spSearchStudents", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter searchParameter = new SqlParameter("@SearchTerm", searchTerm);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(searchParameter);
                con.Open();
                GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to debgug the application after con.Open() line?.

Comment: Yes. It showed no errors.

Comment: Can you connect outside of code using SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string in web.config should be like below one.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBCS" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Since you are getting instance failure,it is problem with the creation of instance of SQL server,just check whether the SQL server is up and running when you execute your application.

To check the services,just type **services.msc** in your run dialogue window.

Comment: I checked services.msc, and the server is running. I tried your connection string (replacing Northwind with the name of my database) and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! My connection string is on the Web.config page which is XML, not C#, so the Data Source should have been ".\SQLEXPRESS" (one \ only!)